# Cast and transform generic attribute values to a flat database view

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, pivot

For reasons out of scope of this question I have a relation that persists generic values of an entity and looks something like this:

```
| group_id::int | id:int |attr_id::text | data_type::text | value::text |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      G1       |   1    |      A       |       varchar   |    lorem    |
|      G1       |   1    |      B       |       integer   |     1001    |
|      G2       |   2    |      B       |       integer   |     1002    |
```

data_type is guaranteed to be one of PostgreSQLs supported data types, so the table (or tables that is, example is simplified) somewhat represents a table definition.

I would like to present this transformed in a different view per group, so the values are cast to their actual data types. Is this even possible?

```
Database View for G1                Database View for G2

| id:int | A::varchar | B::int |    | id:int | B::int |     
--------------------------------    -------------------
|    1   |    lorem   |  1001  |    |   2    |  1002  |
```

I was thinking tablefunc.crosstab would be the way to go but I didn't come very far. I'm just out of ideas. Any help or directions are very welcome.

Comment: I don't think `crosstab` can help you, it doesn't have provision for mixed types. You'll probably have to write some exciting PL/PgSQL code to generate a query to pass to PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE`. Part of what you really want is the `CUBE` feature of grouping sets, which might get added to PostgreSQL 9.5 if the patch is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went for PL/PgSQL.